# Discord.js How to make a change nickname command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a discord.js bot which has already some features. But i wanted to add a command to change a user's nickname.

```
if (command === "changenick") {
    

}
```

This is how i add new commands. Can someone out there help me design this feature?
Also, i am new to discord.js and node.js and i need some explanation of what does what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must **identify which member will have their nickname changed**. I will use menitions for this example.

We grab the collection of mentioned members and grab the first element.

```
const memberToEdit = message.mentions.members.first();
```

---

Next we need to know what the **new nickname** will be. For this example I will use `String#replace()` to remove `[prefix]changenick` and be left with just the text which will be the new nickname. This is assuming you use the setup `[prefix][command name]`

**EDIT:** I forgot to account for the mention being part of the message content, use `String#split()` and `Array#join()` to remove the mention. `.pop()` will return the new nickname and `.trim()` will remove unessesary spaces.

```
const newNickname = message.content.replace(`${prefix}changenick`, '').split(' ').pop().trim();
```

---

Next, we call `setNickname()` on the mentioned member object passing in `newNickname`

```
memberToEdit.setNickname(newNickname);
```

---

Your final code will look like this.

```
if (command === "changenick") {
   const memberToEdit = message.mentions.members.first();
   const newNickname = message.content.replace(`${prefix}changenick`, '').split(' ').pop().trim();
   memberToEdit.setNickname(newNickname);
}
```

Comment: so i ran the command st!changenick @pootis haha and the result was "@<myuserid>haha "

Comment: Forgot about the mention, It have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the message your bot is receiving is called `rMessage`, you can get the `GuildMember` of the author by `rMessage.member`.

`GuildMember` has a method `setNickname(nick)`. So you can do `rMessage.member.setNickname(nick, [reason])` where `nick` is the text they entered and `reason` is optional (it's for putting it in the Audit Log in the server).

Comment: *`setNickname`, not `SetNickname`

Comment: Ah yes, my bad. It is `setNickname`.

Comment: Well, it crashes the bot. It's like this? mesage.member.setNickname(nick);

Comment: @stationaryStation `nick` is a variable. If you didn't define `nick` it would be `undefined` and therefore unable to change the nickname. You can simply fix this by declaring `nick` before the line, like `let nick = "newNameGoesHere";`.

Answer (score -1):

There is already a command to change your nickname on a server; just use /nick `the name you want`

Comment: I think OP wants to change someone else's nickname.

Comment: Well that was fast. On my servers and my friend servers slash commands are disabled and we don't have permissions. And i want to change an user's nickname

Comment: The purpose of DJS is to develop code, using a built-in slash command is an irrelevant solution.